# Wrong tooltip for "people reached" when viewing other user profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, tooltips

I was visiting [Shog9 's profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9) to see what his best posts were (I'm not stalking, I'm trying to learn from the masters). I then saw that he impacted over 1 million people, blah blah blah. When I hovered over the part that said people impacted (as shown in red freehand, on my profile):
[image]

It says:

> Estimate number of times people viewed your helpful posts (based on page views of your questions and questions where you wrote highly-ranked answers)

Clearly Shog9 impacted about 40x more than people than I did yet when I hovered over that same part in Shog9 's profile, it said the same thing. It can be confusing because ***I*** didn't impacted that many people, Shog9 did. This can be said when hovering over that part in anyone's profile (probably other than Community's profile).

So can we change this text from:

> Estimate number of times people viewed your helpful posts (based on page views of your questions and questions where you wrote highly-ranked answers)

to

> Estimate number of times people viewed this user's helpful posts (based on page views of this user's questions and questions where this user wrote highly-ranked answers)

This should be implied when viewing someone else's profile when hovering over the part circled in red, especially above the number. Thank you for considering this request. I am meaning changing the tooltip...

Comment: I'm 99% sure it is a bug, not by design. (simple overlook)

Comment: If it is by-design, I will change it back to feature-request.

Comment: Of course it's a bug, not by design :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With you in the next build.

This copy changed a few times - looks like we ended up settling on phrasing that included "your" and didn't account for others viewing the profile.

Comment: Thank you! I will be watching out for it!