# What happened to the other people? My Impact (people reached) just dropped

Tags: support, status-bydesign, profile-page, people-reached

I posted this [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251070/wrong-tooltip-for-people-reached-when-viewing-other-user-profile) a few weeks ago. The photo I posted shows that I had impacted 25k people. Now it says this:
[image]

I only impacted 1k people, 24k less than what my impact was a few weeks ago! I am sure that 24k people didn't delete their accounts within a few weeks and this is probably a bug. What happened to my impact score?

Comment: It's been estimated that over 100K people die every day. You're lucky you only lost 25K views...

Comment: Seriously? That is crazy to think that in 3 weeks, 24k people deleted their accounts and died.

Comment: Second I only lost 24k. If I lost all 25k, I would be at 0...

Comment: Nothing in life is certain but death and caching.

Comment: @Shog9 Yeah but you know there were about [350K births per day in 2002](http://esa.un.org/wpp/Excel-Data/fertility.htm), that's a lot of legal new users per day.

Comment: Yeah, but they're all busy reading Lifehacks.

Comment: @Thomas support question can't really be "by design", or more accurate to say it's always by design, as it means a question about existing feature. (so we can, in theory, mark all support questions as "by design" ;))

Comment: That said, there are currently [165 such questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-bydesign+support+-bug), so guess I've already lost my pendantic battle... :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard You're... indeed being a little bit pedantic (especially considering you actually included that in your own answer). There was a flag that the official stance was a bit unclear from reading the question, so I thought I'd add a tag to address that. I think it's fine here.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Well, you did post an answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250690/152859), which has positive score, and the question got 24K views - exactly what you are missing.

However, as explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here):

> That's how we got to the current method, which counts views on the following:
>
> **Answers** - Views of the parent question for answers that are:
>
> - Non-deleted AND
> - Score > 0 AND
> - Also meets one or more of the following criteria:
>
>   - In the top 3 answers OR
>   - Is the Accepted Answer OR
>   - Score >= 5 OR
>   - Has at least 20% of the total vote count

So in the first few days after posting your answer, its score was enough to satisfy the last condition above (Has at least 20% of the total vote count) but as new answers were posted there with more and more votes, you lost the impact.

Bottom line: [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

Comment: This is correct - the methodology has two significant "super-weird" possibilities, both of which are pretty darn rare.   This is one: if a question gets a very large number of views quickly, and THEN attracts a very large number of answers after yours AND yours has fewer than 5 votes, AND it isn't in the top 3, AND its not accepted  you can potentially pick up a noticible increase here that's then lost.  Which is weird.  But is fairly rare.  I think this meta post may literally have more answers than any other.

Comment: @PythonMaster please don't put wrong and misleading info in my answer. I checked now and the official post by SE employee still clearly says **bigger than 5**, not bigger or equals. If you have proof it's not the case, please provide link first. And even so, first fix that original post I am quoting

Comment: ??? My answer just got a score of five and my impact just increased by like 25k

Comment: @PythonMaster what answer? Did you carefully check all the other criteria?

Comment: This one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250690/278543

Comment: @PythonMaster well, agree it *looks like* you're correct but it might also be a bug as far as we know. We can't change features based on what we see. Feel free to start a new support question or bug report explaining what happened in your case and we'll see.

Comment: You are wrong... the second link says at least a score of five not more than five.

Comment: @PythonMaster this time you are right, a dev edited it now and fixed the incorrect information in there. Thanks!

Comment: Could anyone tell me what score>5 means here? thx

Comment: @Zinna it means score bigger (more than) five. (The ">" sign is used in basic math and means "the item to the left is greater than the item to the right")

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMaskV2 Obviously yours is no the answer I am looking for. I want to know what the score really means here? How can you get the score that counts for this?

Comment: @Zinna score is upvotes minus downvotes. For example if there are 5 upvotes and 3 downvotes, the score will be 2. Hope it's clear?