# My Impact Rose... But My Answer Never Made the Requirements

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, answers, people-reached

According to this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251662/278543), my answer or any answer must reach all the necessary criteria to be able increase the People Reached score of the answerer:

> **Answers** - Views of the parent question for answers that are:
>
> - Non-deleted AND
> - Score > 0 AND
> - Also meets one or more of the following criteria:
>
>   - In the top 3 answers OR
>   - Is the Accepted Answer OR
>   - Score >5 OR
>   - Has at least 20% of the total vote count

Of course, that was a response to my question on why my stats dropped so dramatically. My answer seemed to fail the criteria in the future as I lost about 24-26k in impact. Now that specific [answer in question got a score of 5](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249951/help-us-test-the-shiny-new-user-activity-page-plus-a-bunch-of-new-features/250690#250690) recently and my impact raised by 26k immediately (well after caching). Now the answer is not in the top three, is not accepted, and does not have at least 20 percent of the total vote count. Seemingly, the only other way I gained that much is that I meet the third of the third criteria.

After a nice conversation with Shadow Wizard, who thought this was a bug, I now would like to know whether this is a bug or just an new update that no one know about. So is it a bug or a new update? If it is a bug, I will be happy to lose that glitched amount of impact... if either what could I have done to gain that much impact?

Comment: What day/time did you see the people reached go back up by 26k?  I strongly think there should be another mandatory criteria added: "must be in the top 30 answers" (the first page)

Comment: Eh? Not a bug and not a new update. It meets the third criteria of the third bullet, meaning it is eligible.

Comment: @Oded that bullet was initially wrong, hence the confusion here. (and Jaydles ignored a comment I posted a while ago.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is not deleted, so bullet 1 is satisfied.

The answer has a positive score, so bullet 2 is satisfied.

The answer has a score of 5 so meets the third criteria of the third bullet.

Making it eligible.

If there is a bug (?), is in the description of the third criteria of the third bullet - it should be "Score 5 or greater".

Comment: Since 5>5 is a false statement, this is a documentation bug, and not by-design.

Comment: Ah I see, Shadow Wizard though that "at least five" was >5 instead of >=5

Comment: @PythonMaster no, Oded changed it to "at least five" today (you can click the "edited" link to see revisions). Before that it was >5 which is no doubt "more than 5", and was wrong as we now know. Even the team is wrong sometimes. :)

Comment: Lol right? @ShadowWizard